# Mouse clicks in a dialog box created from a context menu

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, modal-dialog, contextmenu

I have an MFC dialog based app with a context menu. An entry in the context menu brings up a modal dialog box. But clicking the mouse anywhere in that second dialog box doesn't do anything. Bringing up the same dialog box via the main menu works great. It is like the context menu is somehow stealing the mouse clicks. The code I have that brings up the context menu is:

```
void Cxxx::OnContextMenu(CWnd* pWnd, CPoint ptScreen)
{
    CMenu menu;

    VERIFY(menu.LoadMenu(IDR_MAIN_WINDOW_RIGHT_MOUSE));
    CMenu* pPopup = menu.GetSubMenu(0);
    ASSERT(pPopup != NULL);
    pPopup->TrackPopupMenu(TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_RIGHTBUTTON, ptScreen.x, ptScreen.y, this);
}
```

The code that the context menu uses to bring up the dialog box is:

```
void Cxxx::OnPaste()
{
    CPasteDlg Dlg;
    ...
    if (Dlg.DoModal() != IDOK){
        ...
    }
}
```

The OnPaste code is the exact same api that the main menu uses, and that works fine from the main menu.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong that is preventing the mouse from working inside that paste dialog whenever it is brought up via the context menu?

If it matters, I am using Visual Studio 11 on Win7-64 bit.

Thanks in advance for any help that you can provide.

Comment: Just a guess, give the dlg constructor the correct parent window, this may be a problem, when you have other popup windows...

Comment: Have you tried *CPasteDlg dlg(this);*?

Answer (score 0):

Have you remembered to do everything correctly? I have just created a test application to show a popup menu and show a dialog based on the subsequent mouse click:

```
// TestDlg.cpp : implementation file
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Test.h"
#include "TestDlg.h"
#include "afxdialogex.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif


// CAboutDlg dialog used for App About

class CAboutDlg : public CDialogEx
{
public:
    CAboutDlg();

// Dialog Data
#ifdef AFX_DESIGN_TIME
    enum { IDD = IDD_ABOUTBOX };
#endif

    protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support

// Implementation
protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

CAboutDlg::CAboutDlg() : CDialogEx(IDD_ABOUTBOX)
{
}

void CAboutDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CAboutDlg, CDialogEx)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// CTestDlg dialog



CTestDlg::CTestDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialogEx(IDD_TEST_DIALOG, pParent)
{
    m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);
}

void CTestDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CTestDlg, CDialogEx)
    ON_WM_SYSCOMMAND()
    ON_WM_PAINT()
    ON_WM_QUERYDRAGICON()
    ON_WM_CONTEXTMENU()
    ON_COMMAND(ID_TEST_SHOWDIALOG, &CTestDlg::OnTestShowdialog)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// CTestDlg message handlers

BOOL CTestDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

    // Add "About..." menu item to system menu.

    // IDM_ABOUTBOX must be in the system command range.
    ASSERT((IDM_ABOUTBOX & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX);
    ASSERT(IDM_ABOUTBOX < 0xF000);

    CMenu* pSysMenu = GetSystemMenu(FALSE);
    if (pSysMenu != NULL)
    {
        BOOL bNameValid;
        CString strAboutMenu;
        bNameValid = strAboutMenu.LoadString(IDS_ABOUTBOX);
        ASSERT(bNameValid);
        if (!strAboutMenu.IsEmpty())
        {
            pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_SEPARATOR);
            pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_STRING, IDM_ABOUTBOX, strAboutMenu);
        }
    }

    // Set the icon for this dialog.  The framework does this automatically
    //  when the application's main window is not a dialog
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, TRUE);         // Set big icon
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, FALSE);        // Set small icon

    // TODO: Add extra initialization here

    return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}

void CTestDlg::OnSysCommand(UINT nID, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if ((nID & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX)
    {
        CAboutDlg dlgAbout;
        dlgAbout.DoModal();
    }
    else
    {
        CDialogEx::OnSysCommand(nID, lParam);
    }
}

// If you add a minimize button to your dialog, you will need the code below
//  to draw the icon.  For MFC applications using the document/view model,
//  this is automatically done for you by the framework.

void CTestDlg::OnPaint()
{
    if (IsIconic())
    {
        CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting

        SendMessage(WM_ICONERASEBKGND, reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(dc.GetSafeHdc()), 0);

        // Center icon in client rectangle
        int cxIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON);
        int cyIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON);
        CRect rect;
        GetClientRect(&rect);
        int x = (rect.Width() - cxIcon + 1) / 2;
        int y = (rect.Height() - cyIcon + 1) / 2;

        // Draw the icon
        dc.DrawIcon(x, y, m_hIcon);
    }
    else
    {
        CDialogEx::OnPaint();
    }
}

// The system calls this function to obtain the cursor to display while the user drags
//  the minimized window.
HCURSOR CTestDlg::OnQueryDragIcon()
{
    return static_cast<HCURSOR>(m_hIcon);
}



void CTestDlg::OnContextMenu(CWnd* /*pWnd*/, CPoint point)
{
    CMenu menu;

    VERIFY(menu.LoadMenu(IDR_MENU1));
    CMenu* pPopup = menu.GetSubMenu(0);
    ASSERT(pPopup != nullptr);
    pPopup->TrackPopupMenu(TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_RIGHTBUTTON, point.x, point.y, this);
}


void CTestDlg::OnTestShowdialog()
{
    CAboutDlg dlgAbout;

    dlgAbout.DoModal();
}
```

Does this help? We don't see the rest of your code or dialog resources.

Answer (score -1):

Use `NM_RCLICK` instead of `OnConTextMenu()`

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CXXX, CVIEW2)
    ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT(NM_RCLICK, &CXXX::OnNMRClick)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

VOID CXXX::OnNMRClick(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    CPoint pt1, pt2;
    GetCursorPost(&pt1);
    pt2 = pt1;

    //TODO: Add your code with pt2, pt1 here.
    //TODO: Add your event code here.

    CMenu menu;
    if(menu.LoadMenu(IDR_MAIN_MENU))
    {
        CMenu *pMenu_sub = menu.GetSubMenu(2);
        pMenu_sub->TrackPopupMenu(TPM_LEFTALIGN,pt2.x, pt2.y, this);
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: This is a bad advice. What about the context menu key?